# How can I inject properties for test and for main into each sub module of a multi-module gradle spring boot project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multi-module

This is the structure of my project.

- The parent contains no code.
- module child1 is a spring boot application.
- modules child2, child3 are jars libraries.
- child1 depends on child2 and child3

```
parent
      | build.gradle
      | settings.gradle
      | [no code]
child1
      | build.gradle
      | src/
          | main/
              | java/
              | resources/
                  | application.properties
          | test/
              | java/
              | resources/
                  | application.properties
child2
      | build.gradle
      | src/
          | main/
              | java/
          | test/
              | java/
child3
      | build.gradle
      | src/
          | main/
              | java/
          | test/
              | java/
```

I have a property called "datapath" that I would like to inject into classes in each of the modules.
There are two possible values for "datapath", one for tests and one for production.
I set the production value in 
child1/src/main/resources/application.properties
and the test value in 
child1/src/test/resources/application.properties

I have tried creating configuration classes and specifying PropertySource. 
But the result has been that though child1 picks up the correct application properties in both test and main, spring does not find them in other modules.

Can you propose a strategy for me to implement this?

In particular:

1. The tests in the child1 are annotated SpringBootTest but preferably child2 and child3 should not depend on spring boot (just spring framework for autowiring)
2. I would like to be able to use the @Value annotation on configuration classes in the child modules.
3. How do I direct spring to resolve these properties from the application.properties in the child1 module, using the one in src/test/resources for tests and the one in src/main/resources for production?
4. As I have chosen a very "classical" structure, I would like to be able to achieve this with as few as possible moving parts. In particular I would prefer not to have to specify paths explicitly in annotations.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that in `child2` and `child3` you need `application.properties` only for test. Then in test you can use `@TestPropertySource` where you can point relative path to properties file in `child1` or add `datapath` explicitly:

```java
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "datapath=value" })
public class Child2Test {
```